# How to select and update from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using PHP and MySQL and I have 2 tables containing the fields `number` and `name`. The `name` field in table1 is empty by default and where there is a row in table2 with a matching number I would like to update the name in table1.

The following pseudocode illustrates this:

```
select number, number 
from table1, table2 
  if number from table1 == number from table2
  then insert or update name from table1 with the value of name from table2
```

Comment: Your Question is not clear !!

Comment: The question is not clear enough for me to give you an exact answer. But I think you are looking for http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: please visit this [link](http://www.4shared.com/rar/MAJT3jqR/table.html) my clearer question along with table structure and image

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you could do

```
UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.number = t2.number
SET t1.name = t2.name
```

A more ANSI answer where you can't rely on joining in an update statement would rely on sub-queries, e.g.:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET name = (SELECT name FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.number = t1.number)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.number = t1.number)
```

The WHERE ensures you are only updating the column where there is a matched row.

Comment: i believe you can help me even more. please see this. [link](http://www.4shared.com/rar/MAJT3jqR/table.html) thanks in advanced